# Where to add context to Sentry-php?

Tags: php, sentry

As explained on Sentry Docs I'm trying to add some context to my PHP Aplication:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/enriching-events/context/

I have placed the configureScope in the exception, but as I only recive the error without the context I ask myself if it's the correct place to set it. I searched and all info I have found is about specific frameworks.

Note: Before you ask, the session data is not empty.

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

Sentry\init([
    'dsn'         => 'https://.......<secret>.........',
    'environment' => Environment::get(),
]);
try {
    new Application();
} catch (\Throwable $exception) {
    Sentry\configureScope(function (Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
        $scope->setExtra('email', Session::get('user_email'));
        $scope->setExtra('cart', Session::get('cart'));
        $scope->setExtra('token', Session::get('token'));
    });
    Sentry\captureException($exception);
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I've tried your exact code and it works perfectly, you did not mention the version of the SDK you are using and also not if you are using the self-hosted version or just sentry.io, this might matter but in general the code you are showing works. Make sure you scroll to the "Additional Data" section in the Sentry UI and are not missing it :)

Answer (score 0):

try looking here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/enriching-events/context/

for example you can capture exception with context

```
\Sentry\withScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($e): void {
  $scope->setContext('character', [
    'name' => 'Mighty Fighter',
    'age' => 19,
    'attack_type' => 'melee'
  ]);

  \Sentry\captureException($e);
});
```

or add context globally for all events

```
\Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
  $scope->setContext('character', [
    'name' => 'Mighty Fighter',
    'age' => 19,
    'attack_type' => 'melee'
  ]);
});
```